# Best practice to use swagger in order to use post method to add a class element without necessarily adding a new related element

Tags: asp.net, api, class, swagger

I have 2 class

```
 public class Article
{
    public int? ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "le tire est obligatoire.")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit avoir au plus 30 caractères.")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]
    public string Titre { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La description est obligatoire.")]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "La description doit avoir au plus 250 caractères.")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "La description doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]

    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Sujet sujet { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Sujet
{
    public int? SujetId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "le domaine est obligatoire.")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Le Titre doit avoir au plus 30 caractères.")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Le Titre doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]
    public string Titre { get; set; } = string.Empty;

   
}
```

I generate 2 controlers for these class using visual studio generateur for post put add and delete and add sujet

[image]

I want to had a new article but i have to had a new sujet

[image]

What is the best way to resolve this ?

Here the post part of the controler for article

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Article>> PostArticle(Article article)
    {
      if (_context.Article == null)
      {
          return Problem("Entity set 'TalentDBContext.Article'  is null.");
      }
        _context.Article.Add(article);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetArticle", new { id = article.ArticleId }, article);
    }
```

thanks for your advices

Comment: If i put [JsonIgnore] on sujet in article there is the same problem

Answer (score 0):

We need to modify the article class like this:

```
    public class Article
{
    public int? ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "le tire est obligatoire.")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit avoir au plus 30 caractères.")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]
    public string Titre { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La description est obligatoire.")]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "La description doit avoir au plus 250 caractères.")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "La description doit avoir au moins 10 caractères.")]

    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int FKSujet { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Sujet? sujet { get; set; } 
}
```

therefore when the model is validated, the suject can be null then there will be no error

we add a fluent command to create the non-null key for the database

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
           .HasOne<Sujet>(s => s.Sujet)
           .WithMany(g => g.Articles)
           .HasForeignKey(k=> k.FKSujet);
        }
```

now in the swagger no need to fill in the structure of a new sujet but just to specify the sujet id. The [JsonIgnor] Hides the json part of suject

The Json visible in swagger is :

```
{
  "titre": "stringstri",
  "description": "stringstri",
  "fkSujet": 0
}
```